# Google Cardboard: How to rotate object while using autowalk in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, google-cardboard, google-vr-sdk

I'm trying to create a car race for Google Cardboard with Unity. I used a autowalk script to control the car with the `Cardboard-VR-SDK` and it works. The car drives in the right direction, but it doesn't rotate in this direction.

Do you have any ideas how to change the rotation of the car while driving?

This is the autowalk script:

https://github.com/JuppOtto/Autowalk-for-Google-VR-SDK-with-Unity/blob/master/Autowalk.cs

Comment: after `transform.Translate(rotation * direction);` you could probably do `transform.rotation = rotation`?

Comment: Thanks but unfortunately that doesn't work. :(